# How to implement fa-bars in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, font-awesome

I have a `jquery` and I am trying to edit it so my nav bar items appear after I clicked the `fa` `fa-bar` but after so many tries I am unable to do it here is my `jquery`

```js
(function() {

  var $menu = $('.navigation nav'),
    optionsList = '<option value="" selected>Go to..</option>';

  $menu.find('li').each(function() {
      var $this = $(this),
        $anchor = $this.children('a'),
        depth = $this.parents('ul').length - 1,
        indent = '';

      if (depth) {
        while (depth > 0) {
          indent += ' - ';
          depth--;
        }

      }
      $(".nav li").parent().addClass("bold");

      optionsList += '<option value="' + $anchor.attr('href') + '">' + indent + ' ' + $anchor.text() + '</option>';
    }).end()
    .after('<select class="selectmenu">' + optionsList + '</select>');

  $('select.selectmenu').on('change', function() {
    window.location = $(this).val();
  });

})();
```

In this `jquery`, my navbar appears a selected `div` but it seems hoggish on a responsive website and I want it to be in a `fa` `fa-bar` instead of selected `div`. Please guide me accordingly

Comment: Post all of your code, so we can test it.

Comment: this is all the code @MiguelCruz i dont understand what are u refering too

Comment: Where is your html? Post it please.